# Read and convert crystal report .rpt file to .csv or .xlsx in python 3

Tags: python, crystal-reports

I'm trying to write a small script in Python3 to open and read bunch of crystal reports .rpt files and convert them to .csv or .xlsx files.

I checked pandas and python3 official docs, but no luck.

I ran file command from my linux machine on one of these files, and it gave me this:
Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 4.10, Code page: 1256, Revision Number: 97

and that lead me to olefile library, and I was able to load the content, but the content is in byte format.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can just help me out on how i might load this byte data (may be decode them first) to pandas and save it to a readable csv or xlsx file.

Thank You,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I did a version by hand because read_fwf and other conversion means couldn't read my .rpt files

```
for file_name in file_names:
    list_all = []
    print('Starting File:', file_name)
    with open(os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, file_name),'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
        i= 0 
        for line in file:
            if i == 1: 
                sizes = re.split(' ',line)
                sizes_ = [len(re.sub('^\-','',x)) for x in sizes]
                break
            i += 1

    with open(os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, file_name), 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:     
        i = 0
        for line in file:
            if i == 0:
                line = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','', line)
            i += 1
            if not line[0:1] in ['Ã','á'] and line[0:3]!='---' and len(line.strip()) > 3 and line[:16] != 'Completion time:':
                grabber = []
                trace = 0
                for dist in sizes_:
                    grabber.append(line[trace:dist+2+trace].strip())
                    trace += dist+2
                list_all.append(grabber)
    headers = ['_'.join(i.split('|')[-1:]) for i in list_all[0]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_all[1:], columns=headers)
    new_name = file_name.replace('.rpt','.csv')
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(PROCCESSED_PATH,new_name), index=False)
    print('Outputted File:', new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import csv
import codecs

with open("holder.csv", "w") as my_empty_csv:
  pass  
#holder.csv is the output file

def convert(inputFile,outputFile):

    writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
    fieldIndexes = []
    headers = ""

    for idx, val in enumerate(inputFile):
        if(idx == 0):
            headers = val
        elif(idx == 1):
            fieldIndexes = list(getFieldIndexes(val," "))
            row = list(getFields(headers,fieldIndexes))
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            row = list(getFields(val,fieldIndexes))
            writer.writerow(row)

def getFieldIndexes(input, sep):
    lastIndex = 0
    for idx, c in enumerate(input):
        if(c == sep):
            yield (lastIndex,idx)
            lastIndex = idx+1
    yield lastIndex, len(input)

def getFields(input, indexes):
    for index in indexes:
        yield input[index[0]:index[1]].strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if(len(sys.argv) == 3):
        with open(sys.argv[1],encoding='utf-8-sig') as inputFile:
            with open(sys.argv[2],'w',newline='') as outputFile:
                convert(inputFile,outputFile)
    else:
        print("Usage: rpt2csv.py inputFile outputFile")
```

source: https://github.com/16bytes/rpt2csv.py